go-grpc-gateway: how to chain multiple http errors
in grpc-gateway how can we chain the multiple error handlers
an eg would be look like this
import "github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway/runtime"

    //first error handler
    var runTimeError1 = func(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
            
            stat, ok := status.FromError(err)
            fmt.Println("body")
            if !ok || len(stat.Details()) != 1 {
                fmt.Println("in unknown error")
            }
            statusCode := runtime.HTTPStatusFromCode(stat.Code())
            fmt.Println("code", statusCode)
        }
    // another error handler
    var runTimeError2 = func(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
            
            stat, ok := status.FromError(err)
            fmt.Println("body")
            if !ok || len(stat.Details()) != 1 {
                fmt.Println("in unknown error")
            }
            statusCode := runtime.HTTPStatusFromCode(stat.Code())
            fmt.Println("code", statusCode)
        }
    
    runtime.HTTPError = runTimeError1

What i would need is to combine the both errors as chain something like this
runtime.HTTPError = [runTimeError1,runTimeError2]
Is it possible to the above implementation in grpc-gateway??

What behavior do yo uexpect? Different handlers for different errors? Or both handlers doing something with the error? In general, you can merge/chain the error handlers yourself into a single handler, and assign that one.

@NotX i would like to chain the error handlers such as one handler will log the error to files or some other log collector and the other error handler will handle the errors for end user (rest API output )

You can merge all the handlers into a single one. Here's a slightly overengineered example:
type ErrHandler func(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error)
type ChainedErrHandler []ErrHandler

func (c ChainedErrHandler) Merge() ErrHandler {
    return func(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
        for _, handler := range c {
            handler(ctx, mux, marshaler, w, r, err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var runTimeError1 ErrHandler = func(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
        fmt.Println("handling error", err, "in handler 1")
    }
    var runTimeError2 ErrHandler = func(ctx context.Context, mux *runtime.ServeMux, marshaler runtime.Marshaler, w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, err error) {
        fmt.Println("handling error", err, "in handler 2")
    }
    chainedHandlers := ChainedErrHandler{runTimeError1, runTimeError2}.Merge()
    runtime.HTTPError = chainedHandlers
}


Thanks for the answer let me try that

@shamonshamsudeen You're welcome! If you need more clarifications, don't hesitate to ask. If you don't and your problem is solved, please mark this answer as "accepted". ;)
